# fs.readdir is not working when I try to read a folder

Tags: javascript, fs

I am trying to read the files from a folder 'data' and the code below should normally work, but I am not able to understand why I am getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: _fs.readdir is not a function`

```
import fs from "fs";

// Have tried the below option too instead of import sytax
// const fs = require("fs");

const dataFolder = "./data/";

// Option #1
fs.readdir(dataFolder, function (_err, files) {
  files.forEach((file) => console.log(file));
});

// OUTPUT
// Uncaught TypeError: _fs.readdir is not a function

// Option #2
fs.readdirSync(dataFolder).forEach((file) => console.log(file));

// OUTPUT
// Uncaught TypeError: _fs.readdirSync is not a function
```

Any help would be appreciated. I assumed that it was the bundler Parcel that was the cause, but I changed it to Webpack and it was still giving the same error.

Comment: Can you provide the full error traceback? Can you provide your webpack config?

Comment: @SuperStormer I am currently using parcel for the bundling.. I had used a basic webpack config while testing.. straight from the tutorials and it gave the same error as parcel so I thought of moving back to parcel.. Regarding the error traceback.. can you help me with how exactly I can get this for you? I am pretty new to this..

Comment: @SuperStormer : I've uploaded the site on netlify.. you can see the error in the console.. hope that helps.. https://brahma-gallery.netlify.app/

Comment: `fs` is a node.js module and is available only on the server-side.

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh : oh ok.. now it makes sense.. will test and check it from that perspective now.. thanks for sharing.. apologies for the trouble..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question, in case it helps some others like me, who are moving from frontend coding to understanding node.js.

It's difficult to grasp that some modules are just not meant for browsers and `fs` is one them and when you try to use 'require' that's another roadblock.. so if, like me, you are here because you tried to use `fs` in your javascript linked to your html to read something from your local machine or server and expected it to show up on the browser, it won't work.

It's a bit frustrating but once you get your head around it, it makes sense. So although this might not be the answer you looked for, I thought I'd just share this so that you don't waste more time, trying to make it work.

Getting to understand node.js and how to use `fs` on node.js would be better use of time..:-)..