# how to test fs.readdir on a local environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Based on my recent struggles and then finding out at `fs` is only available on nodejs (thanks to @ĐăngKhoaĐinh .. [fs.readdir is not working when I try to read a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67553009/fs-readdir-is-not-working-when-i-try-to-read-a-folder))

Do I need to run a nodejs server on my localhost to test `fs`? Or is there a way to do this using just a browser, visual code and nothing else?

Comment: I think this is one of those situations where you're asking a specific question, when really your problem is something else. An [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I suspect if you told us what you're really trying to accomplish, the answer might look totally different from what you're asking

Comment: It seems to me that you want to access the folders and files of a user using a website in a browser. If that's what you want to do, you might have to look into making an app, not a web application

Comment: Hi @TKoL thanks for the response.. ok, to get exactly what I want, it's basically I need to read a folder and then use the folder names as variables to create the path of the image for a gallery.. I assumed it was a frontend application and was using `fs` to make it work but I realised that it's something that might not work only with a browser and that I might need some other solution and I am not sure what this is.. is it that I need to run node server on my localhost? I've tried this but I can't figure out what exactly  should do.. so yes, explaining what I want is a bit tricky..

Comment: @TKoL I've rephrased the question and hopefully it's not an XY Question anymore..:-)..

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:netlify]. Are you actually using that?

Comment: if you need to make an application that has access to the users local filesystem, and your main background is in websites/html/javascript, you might want to check out Electron. Building an electron app is a lot like building a website in a lot of ways, but you also have stuff that native applications have access to like the filesystem, and node.js packages.

Comment: @Quentin : Sorry about that.. have untagged it.. actually the test site was on netlify and I had the link in the question before I edited it.. will ensure I take care of tags in the future.. thanks for pointing it out..

Comment: @TKoL : thanks for the update.. actually it's not to access the users local application.. it's a folder that's dumped into the folder where I have my index.html.. so I am trying to read the content and display the gallery.. the folder could be replaced with newer content (but the same structure) and I'd like my code to pick up the file names in the folder .. can I do this on a local environment without a server setup?

Comment: No, you can't do that kind of stuff in a browser without a server. You could do it with a server, or you could do it with various types of html-supporting application platforms - notably WinJS for Windows Store Apps (which are surprisingly easy to make using html+js) or electron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarise the problem:

*A gallery web app needs to have a list of the images in it*.

---

To directly address the question:

You can't read the user's hard disk from a browser (with `fs` or anything else).

You need to read the place where the images will be kept (which will be a web server in production and not the user's hard disk).

---

There are two places this list can be:

- Baked into the application source code (e.g. as an array)
- At a URL the application can read with Ajax

The latter approach is more common, but requires you be running a web server in your development environment. This is a good idea in general because the fewer differences between development and production the fewer problems you will have moving between the environments.

There are two times the list could be created:

- On demand every time the application is run
- When the application is deployed (to a testing or production environment)

---

The former approach requires server-side capabilities.

This could be as simple as using Apache HTTP with `Options +Indexes` in the configuration (although that isn't the nicest data format to parse with client-side JS after you request the directory listing with Ajax).

This could be some simple server side programming that returns the data in a nice JSON format that is easy to parse.

You'll need the same server-side capabilities in your development and production environments. If you use Apache HTTP then you'll need it in development and production, with the same `Indexs` configuration. If you use Node.js then you'll need hosting that supports Node.js. etc.

---

The latter approach doesn't require anything special from the server at all.

You write a similar program to the one mentioned above that generates JSON, but instead of outputting JSON over HTTP it writes it to a static file.

You run that program on your development machine whenever you make a change (to the directory of images or the file's data format).

When you deploy the application to production, you deploy that file with it.

Comment: Thanks Quentin for the detailed response.. really appreciate you pointing me in the right direction for this..:-)..

Comment: Thanks again Quentin..:-).. I managed to create my first node app!! and was able to use `fs` to output the folder names into an array..:-).. really excited!!!